# jquery object does not support property or method

Tags: jquery, dwr

I am getting error "object does not support property or method" on IE 8 with jquery 1.8 on the following

jQuery(".errorContents");

I am using DWR along with jQuery in my project and also added $.noConflict(); but keep getting the above mentioned error

```
function addError(){
       var errorContents= jQuery(".errorContents");
       errorContents.html('Errors in the Page');
       errorContents.show(); 
}
```

Comment: `jQuery(".errorContents");` is only a selector. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Dygestor I want to write some messages "String text" in the 'errorContents' Div in document but it throws "object does not support property or method" error on jQuery(".errorContents");

Comment: well if `jQuery(".errorContents");` is all you've got, then it probably will throw such error, as that code does nothing useful.. Could you post an example of such page?

Comment: @Dygestor I have added the function where I am getting this error

Comment: did you try removing that variable and simply use `jQuery(".errorContents").html('Errors in the Page');`?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="errorContents">asdf</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addError() {
        var errorContents = $(".errorContents");
        errorContents.html('Errors in the Page');
        errorContents.show();
    }
    addError();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wbb8/

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of multiple loading of same jQuery plugin or loading multiple versions of jQuery plugin.